# Background Image Not scalable in Mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image, viewport

```
/* background image and overlay */

body {
  background: #212121 url("img/bg.jpg") no-repeat top center fixed;
  background-size:cover;
  **strong text**margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%; 
  }
```

Website: https://ejive2k18-07.firebaseapp.com/ -Working perfect in widescreen but not compatible with mobile view.Will be glad if anyone solve this issuse!

Comment: And I have included tags-  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: can you be more presice ont what you want ? as i see it's working fine on the site

Answer (score -1):

If you want the same image to scale based on the size of the browser window:

```
background-image:url('../images/bg.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
background-position:center;
Do not set width, height, or margins.
```

Comment: I have not included width,margins as you said @Eslam Ashour ,problem was not solved still not scalable. Here is the complete code pls feel free to rectfiy the problem   -https://github.com/mvskiren/EJIVE-2k18-Event-Web-App-/blob/master/finalpapperpresent.html

Comment: If you don't mind, Could you please forward me the screenshot of mobile view@Eslam Ashour